# Getting FontAwesome to respect CSS color -- are there FontAwesome quirks?

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

I'm having trouble getting a span (or i) that I'm having represent a particular icon using FontAwesome styles to be the color I want it to be.

The weird thing is that the Chrome inspector *shows* it to "be" the color the CSS says it should be, and it shows that the rule is correctly implemented, but in the browser it appears as the color of the surrounding div, which, again, Chrome inspector shows to be correctly overridden.

Fontawesome works fine, using CSS styling to set color, in other parts of my app.

Has anyone run into any quirks with fontawesome and CSS styles?  Under what circumstances would Chrome inspector show the font as one color but it would display as another?

If you can help, would appreciate.  If not, that's fine, but don't down-vote me, if you would.

Comment: why you using <span> & <i> both for same functionality? Or is it a mistake?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Either from http://JSfiddle.net or a Stack snippet.

Comment: i and span can be used for the same purpose according to fontawesome -- they use i, they say span is more semantically correct.

Comment: If I can I will add an example.  I had thought this might be a quirk of fontaweseome that someone had run into before.  Fontawesome is working fine in other parts of my code -- using the same sort of CSS styling as above. -- To whomever _already_ down voted me -- wow, thanks.  It makes one really wary using StackOverflow.  I don't think my question is that silly -- again, I am certain there are some quirks to fontawesome that someone must have run into before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your problem, you don't have any text in the `<span>`. 
But even if you add some, you're hiding the parent element by calling:

```
#la-tarifa-es{
        display: none
}
```

So all of the children will be hidden as well regardless of how you target them.

Comment: Right, thanks.  I think the code I included obfuscated the issue.  -- Sorry for that. -- In fact that's a complete separate div. -- The issue is that fontawesome adds a before:: to the span, and puts in a character.  Normally this works fine, and I can style it using CSS.  This time, however, it simply refuses -- although the Chrome inspector shows everything hunky-dory.  I appreciate the help.  If I have the time I'll put the code online, although I think it will be hard to minimise the example, as there's something really quirky about this particular code that's giving me a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that FontAwesome works by adding a ::before to the SPAN (or I).  So, apparently, the CSS rule for the containing DIV was operating on that, not the CSS rule for the SPAN.  When I made a very specific rule for SPAN::BEFORE it worked.